# Dependent Kendo Grid with Dynamic Filter Preventing Adding Records

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Okay, so I have two observable datasources.  One uses a model called TestRequest, of which I can have multiples.  The other uses a model of TestResult of which multiples can exist for each TestRequest.  I have a requestId data item that I am filtering on to populate my dependent grid.  With declarative data and a declarative filter everything works fine.  If I dynamically set the filter, I can no longer add new records to the filtered datasource.  How can I get around this?  I was going to set the "foreign" id in a handler on the data source's change event (this is how I maintain client side primary keys just fine).   And I can I can tell from my handler that the "add" action is firing, but the editor popup (I am using popup editing on both grids) is not showing?  Is there some other magic I need to enable?

Let me know if I need to post code and I will put my html and js up on a server for y'all to look at and criticize :)

Thanks in advance.

Relevant JavaScript:

```
var TestRequest = kendo.data.Model.define({
    id: "Id",
    fields: {
        "accessionNumber": { type: "string" },
        "specimenCollectionDate": { type: "date" },
        "specimenReceivedDate": { type: "date" },
        "resultReportDate": { type: "date" },
        "testDescription": { type: "string" },
        "relevantClincalInfo": { type: "string" },
        "specimenSource": { type: "string" },
        "resultStatus": { type: "string" },
        "reasonForTest": { type: "string" },
        "comments": { type: "string" }
    }
});

var testRequestDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    schema: {
        model: TestRequest
    }
});

testRequestDataSource.bind("change", function(e) {
    if (e.action === "add") {
        e.items[0].dirty = true;
        kendo.data.ObservableObject.fn.set.call(e.items[0], "Id", viewModel.testsResults.nextRequestId);
        viewModel.testsResults.nextRequestId++;
    }
});

var TestResult = kendo.data.Model.define({
    id: "Id",
    fields: {
        "requestId": {
            type: "number",
            editable: false
        },
        "foo": {
            type: "string"
        }
    }
});

var testResultDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: [
        {
            Id: 1,
            requestId: 1,
            foo: "bar"
        },
        {
            Id: 2,
            requestId: 1,
            foo: "baz"
        },
        {
            Id: 3,
            requestId: 2,
            foo: "beep"
        }
    ],
    schema: {
        model: TestResult
    },
    filter: {
        "field": "requestId",
        "operator": "eq",
        "value": 0
    }
});

testResultDataSource.bind("change", function(e){
    if (e.action === "add") {
        e.items[0].dirty = true;
        kendo.data.ObservableObject.fn.set.call(e.items[0], "Id", viewModel.testsResults.nextResulttId);
        viewModel.testsResults.nextResultId++;
    }
});

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    ...
    testsResults: {
        nextRequestId: 1,
        nextResultId: 4,
        testRequests: testRequestDataSource,
        testResults: testResultDataSource,
        testRequestChange: function() {
            var selectedItems =testRequestGrid.select();
            var selectedRow = $(selectedItems[0]);
            var selectedUid = selectedRow.data("uid");
            var selectedData = testRequestGrid.dataSource.getByUid(selectedUid);
            var requestId = selectedData.id;
            this.testsResults.testResults.filter({
                "field":"requestId",
                "operator":"eq",
                "value": requestId
            });
        },
        testRequestEdited: function(e) {
            var uid = e.model.uid;
            // TODO: fix below code to use callback or better event
            setTimeout(function() {
                testRequestGrid.select(testRequestGrid.tbody.find(">tr[data-uid='"+uid+"']"));
            }, 100);
        },
        ....

....
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="testsResults">
    <h2>Tests/Results</h2>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Test Requests</legend>
        <div id="testRequests">
            <div data-role="grid"
                 data-bind="source: testsResults.testRequests, events: { change: testsResults.testRequestChange, save: testsResults.testRequestEdited }"
                 data-editable="popup"
                 data-selectable="true"
                 data-toolbar='["create"]'
                 data-columns='[{"field":"accessionNumber","title":"Accession #"},
                                {"field":"specimenCollectionDate", "title":"Specimen Collection Date", "hidden":"true"},
                                {"field":"specimenReceivedDate", "title":"Specimen Received Date", "hidden":"true"},
                                {"field":"resultReportDate", "title":"Result Report Date", "hidden":"true"},
                                {"field":"testDescription","title":"Test Description"},
                                {"field":"relevantClinicalInfo", "title":"Relevant Clinical Information", "hidden":"true"},
                                {"field":"specimenSource","title":"Specimen Source", "hidden":"true"},
                                {"field":"resultStatus","title":"Result Status","hidden":"true"},
                                {"field":"reasonForTest","title":"Reason For Test", "hidden":"true"},
                                {"field":"comments","title":"Comments","hidden":"true"},
                                {"command":["edit","destroy"], "title":" ", "width":"170px"}]'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Test Results</legend>
        <div id="testResults">
            <div data-role="grid"
                 data-bind="source: testsResults.testResults"
                 data-editable="popup"
                 data-selectable="true"
                 data-toolbar='["create"]'
                 data-columns='[{"field":"requestId","title": "Test Request ID", "hidden":"true"},
                                {"field":"foo", "title":"Foo"},
                                {"command":["edit","destroy"], "title":" ", "width":"170px"}]'>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: I added as much of the JavaScript and the bound HTML as I thought was necessary.  If y'all need more to see where I have gone astray, please let me know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay!  I get to answer my own question.  The problem is that the new record does NOT match the filter, so the edit popup cannot display.  I added the missing piece in the change event handler of the data source and everything works nifty:

```
testResultDataSource.bind("change", function(e){
    if (e.action === "add") {
        e.items[0].dirty = true;
        kendo.data.ObservableObject.fn.set.call(e.items[0], "Id", viewModel.testsResults.nextResulttId);
        var filters = this.filter().filters;
        var requestId = filters[0].value;
        kendo.data.ObservableObject.fn.set.call(e.items[0], "requestId", requestId);
        viewModel.testsResults.nextResultId++;
}
```

});

Comment: Where is `viewModel` declared and what is it?